# RAILS: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this when I try to "bundle"

> Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/ Bundler could not find
>   compatible versions for gem "actionpack":   In Gemfile:
>
> ```
> sass-rails (= 3.1.5) ruby depends on
>   actionpack (~> 3.1.0) ruby
>
> rails (= 3.2.0) ruby depends on
>   actionpack (3.2.0)
> ```

And, this is my Gemfile:

```
  source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.7.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '1.0.18'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.7.0'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.4.3.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end
```

Need help. thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3.2.0 release notes states that you should upgrade these gems :

```
sass-rails ~> 3.2.3
coffee-rails ~> 3.2.1
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.2.3 of sass-rails will support Rails 3.2, so change your Gemfile to read:

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
```

You might want to relax other gem versions too, so they can automatically upgrade when you upgrade Rails. It's the Gemfile.lock that holds the versions, so only specify the gem version in your Gemfile when you have a good reason to do so.